# What is the correct string sort order?

Tags: c#, string, sorting

```
   string[] words = { "aaaa", "a-aaa", "bbbb", "b-bbbb", "000"};
   var sortedWords =
            from w in words
            orderby w
            select w;
```

When I run this query the expected order is 000, a-aaa,aaaa,b-bbbb and bbbb.

But the actual result is 000, aaaa,a-aaa,bbbb and b-bbbb.

I verified with SQL server its giving same as LINQ result. Is my understanding wrong or is it a bug?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "Is my understanding is wrong or bug?" - almost certainly the former :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9355086/11640) for the related question. Hyphen is a special case when you sort strings with default culture-specific comparer.

Comment: thank you. This solution doesn't suit for all scenarios. For  example, if you are writing SharePoint CAML query then applying this solution doesn't work well.

Comment: @Yass: so are you trying to write a query in CAML? what is the question?

Comment: yes, as i mentioned earlier, i tried in SQL server as well as in CAML query, both return the same values.If we have to implement culture specific sorting, i feel its complicated.