# String.Compare() 2 Strings

Tags: c#

while i was learning (reading Essential C# 6 5th Edition) the `String.Compare()` method i read that if i have lets say 1 string `text1` and 1 string `text2` when comparing that i get a number:

```
// 0 if equal
// negative if text1 < text2
// positive if text1 > text2
```

so when i do this

```
string text1 = "Hello";
string text2 = "Hello";

int result = string.Compare(text1, text2);

Console.Write(result); // I get 0 which means equal which is correct.
```

But if i do:

```
string text1 = "Helo";
string text2 = "Hello";

int result = string.Compare(text1, text2);

Console.Write(result); // I get 1. Shouldn't i be getting -1? Doing the opposite meaning that i have text1 = "Hello" and text 2 = "Helo" produces -1 when it should produce 1 correct?
```

Why does that happen or am i missing (messing) something/with something?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354966/string-sorting-issue-in-c-sharp

Comment: Have you seen dictionary (like a book)? "Helo" > "Hello"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compares each character in the appering order: H = H, E = E, L = L, O > L and then it stops. So `Helo` > `Hello` simply because `l` is before `o` in the alphabet.

More info can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx)

Comment: Oh i thought it compares to see if there are equal characters in both string meaning numbers for example 5 characters in 1 string and 5 in another.

Comment: Or am i mistaking it with the String.Equals() method?

Comment: No. It compares the ASCII code for each character in the string actually. If you need to compare the length of string you can use something like this: `text1.Length > text2.Length`

Comment: `String.Equls` compare you string and if they are equal then it returns `true` else `false`. `String.Equals(text1, text2)` is like `String.Compare(text1, text2) == 0`

Comment: Thanks chosen best answer only 1 thing if you can help understand a usage where String.Compare would be useful. Why would someone want to compare individual characters inside a string. Like it seams to me extremely rare where there would be a usage to compare e.g. helo to hello and get that helo is bigger. Or is it indeed used for those rare cases?

Comment: @GeorgeOscStephan To put strings in alphabetical order like you would find them in a dictionary.  That's not rare at all.